# Create custom InputMask In Android

Tags: android, input-mask

How to create custom input mask in Android.
For Example,  need DFSU 618908 that means 4 digits in the beginning is alphabets, then space, then 7 digits.

In web development, I can use [InputMaskRobinHerbots](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)
I've been google, I found this [RedMadRonbot](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android) but written in kotlin, which is I am not familiar.

How can I just create in a mask using TextWatcher for my case...?

Any help it so appreciated.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDialogNomorContainerDeliveryEkspor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>
```

In my Activity just

```
EditText nomorContainer = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogNomorContainerDeliveryEkspor);
//some TextWatcher perhaps
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using `TextWatcher` to create custom `InputMask`

Create this class that overrides `TextWatcher`

```
  public class SsnMask implements TextWatcher {

private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 9;
private static final int MIN_LENGTH = 3;

private String updatedText;
private boolean editing;

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (text.toString().equals(updatedText) || editing) return;

    String digits = text.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");
    int length = digits.length();

    if (length <= MIN_LENGTH) {
        updatedText = digits;
        return;
    }

    if (length > MAX_LENGTH) {
        digits = digits.substring(0, MAX_LENGTH);
    }

    if (length <= 5) {
        String firstPart = digits.substring(0, 3);
        String secondPart = digits.substring(3);

        updatedText = String.format(Locale.US, "%s-%s", firstPart, secondPart);
    }
    else {
        String firstPart = digits.substring(0, 3);
        String secondPart = digits.substring(3, 5);
        String thirdPart = digits.substring(5);

        updatedText = String.format(Locale.US, "%s-%s-%s", firstPart, secondPart, thirdPart);
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (editing) return;

    editing = true;

    editable.clear();
    editable.insert(0, updatedText);

    editing = false;
}
```

}

Then you just apply it like this

```
    ssnET = view.findViewById(R.id.ssnET);
    ssnET.addTextChangedListener(new SsnMask());
```

Comment: It is the best solution I found until now. But, there is a small annoyance. If we move the cursor towards beginning of a string and delete a char, the cursor immediately jumps back to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

An [input-mask-android](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android) author here.

The library is actually interoperable with Java. There's even a [Quick Start](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/wiki/Quick-Start) page in our Wiki with Java sample code.